# google chrome language change for windows 8.1

Tags: google-chrome

I have recently installed windows 8.1 pirated version on my laptop. And also installed chrome by downloading from opera browser. But whenever I open google chrome it always opens up in unknown language. I tried changing the language from settings. but it didn't work. So what can I do now?

I am attaching the screenshot of chrome for further understanding.

[image]

Comment: https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!profile/chrome/APn2wQeZpd70xdl5U4MNbZGjpuscxMu2haFHGvzzshp9bDTfNWpkIZ1cD9uN6rISFE4ItVxn1gSa/chrome/p3TkTgKxojw/3Pxh-CtOBmoJ

Comment: It didn't helped.

Comment: English (United States)

Comment: posted an answer check it

Answer (score 0):

go to your,

settings-> languages

click on dotted vertical icon, chose `Display google chrome in this language`

and then relaunch...

[image]

Comment: Unable to find these options as it is in another language. I can't understand the whole page layout. Here is the link of my chrome page.

Comment: file:///C:/Users/user/Pictures/Screenshots/Screenshot%20(2).png

Comment: ur chrome was translated .. so use this URL chrome://settings/ in address bar... and then click very bottom of the page .. in blue line +show advanced ( might be in translated) but you can find at end of the page on left side

Comment: then find language in 11 th title , count bold one ... there select that box.. then you can find english over there

Comment: I tried as per your suggestion, but english language was not available there in the option.

Comment: then add it there is add options. may be you cant get it because it was in other language.. there is only one button which is add .. click that too add language you want.. include english